# Twilio outbound call auto dialing twice if rejected by callee

Tags: twilio

I am facing an issue that whenever i place the outbound call from soft dialer(browser application) and the call is rejected by the callee(mobile phone) then twilio is again dialing to the same callee automatically. But this does not happen when the callee rejects the second call which was generated automatically by twilio.

Javascript related twilio code:

```
const makeOutboundCall = () => {
let outboundCall = device.connect({        
    To: TO_NUMBER
});

outboundCall.on("ringing", (hasEarlyMedia) => {
    console.log("The call has started and the other phone is ringing.");
});

outboundCall.on("accept", (connection) => {
    console.log("The other person answered the phone!");
});

outboundCall.on("disconnect", () => {
  console.log("The other person hung up.");
});
```

}

Server side Java webhook looks like below:

```
public String callByBrowserToMobile(@RequestParam String ApplicationSid, @RequestParam String ApiVersion, @RequestParam String Called, @RequestParam String Caller, @RequestParam String CallStatus, @RequestParam String To, @RequestParam String From, @RequestParam String CallSid,@RequestParam String Direction, @RequestParam String AccountSid)
```

{

```
  Number number = new Number.Builder(To).build();
  Dial dial = new Dial.Builder().answerOnBridge(true).number(number).callerId(myTwilioNumber).build();
  VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).build();
  logger.info(response.toXml());              
  return response.toXml();
```

}

answerOnBridge(true) is used to track the ringing and accept state of the outbound call at UI side.
The issue is replicable using the github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-js as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best handled by opening a [support ticket](https://www.twilio.com/console/support/tickets/create). The terminating service provider could be returning an incorrect [SIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261) response code which is causing Twilio to attempt delivery across another provider (and thus the 2nd call), as the response code indicates that a carrier isn't able to terminate the call.

[Example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking#multiple-orig-uris):

> If any of the following SIP status codes are returned ("2xx", "400",
> "404", "405", "410", "416", "482", "484", "486", "6xx"), Twilio will
> not fail over to the next origination SIP URI.